# Drupal How to set up a page https

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, https

I'm using *drupal 6* . What are the steps or procedure to set up a page with **https** instead of **http**. Can anyone guide me because i dont nothing about this security. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Secure Pages module that Haza mentioned will help you configure Drupal to use HTTPS, once you've configured your web server to with a secure certificate. Assuming you're using Apache, this O'Reilly article on [Configuring SSL Under Apache](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html) may help you get the server set up to support https, in the first place. However, if you're using a hosting company, the easiest thing to do would be to have them configure it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) module.